# Why int[char*] is valid and returns char*?

Tags: c++

I found this and tried to figure out why it's valid.

```
int main(int ac, char* av[])  
{ return ac[av]==0; } //returns 0
```

I found out that `ac[av]` returns `char*` so then when comparing it to 0 it's obvious it will return 0 .
But why can we use square brackets on integer variable?
Why `int[char*]` returns `char*`?

Comment: `x[y]`, `y[x]`, and `*(x + y)` all mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, was unable to find that answer.